# Search/replace array of characters pointed to by a character pointer in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers

Here's my function call:

```
removeTags(*buf, bufSize);
```

which calls:

```
void removeTags(char* dataBlock, unsigned long size) 
{
    char* start = dataBlock; 
    char* end = dataBlock + size;

    while(start < end)
    {
    //How do I replace the characters "\abc" with just nothing, ''.
        }
```

I want to replace any instances of the characters \abc with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you find an instance of `\abc` simply move all the characters after the `\abc` backwards four places (four because `\abc` is four chars long) (possibly using `memmove`).

For instance:

```
one two \abc three
        <----^ copy everything from the 't' down backwards over the \abc
```

Note that after you do that, your `end` pointer will be invalidated so you'll have to update it.

Finding the position of a string within another string can be done with `strstr` for `const char*`s or `std::string::find` for `std::string`s. Of course, if you're using `std::string`, then you could just use `std::string::replace`.

Comment: Any downside to setting pointer's memory content = to a string and just doing the string replacing: string xyz = *buf; The buf pointer is output to a file in the next line anyway. This app converts an old ebook format to an RTF file. I don't understand pointers well enough to do this search and replace. Seems to work fine converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You remove the unwanted characters by moving all the following characters down.

You should be able to do it in a single pass by having a from_pointer and a to_pointer and either copy the current at from_pointer to to_pointer or increment from_pointer to skip over the characters you're omitting.